# How group by two fields in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a following `reportfinals` collection and it has the following format:

```
{
  username: 123,
  rxm_number: 5,
  shelf_number: 12345
}
```

There may be more documents as well. I wanted to group both by `rxm_number` and `shelf_number` and count `username` to display something like this:

```
[
 {
   rxm_number: 1,
   shelf_number: 1235,
   users: 150
 },
{
   rxm_number: 1,
   shelf_number: 442,
   users: 68
 },
{
   rxm_number: 2,
   shelf_number: 44,
   users: 68
 },
]
```

I used the aggregate function with `$group` and `$project` and my query looks like this:

```
db.reportfinals.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: '$rxm_number', 
        shelf_number: {$addToSet: '$shelf_number'}, 
        users: {$addToSet: '$username'},

    }},
    {$project: {
        _id: 0, 
        rxm_number: '$_id', 
        shelf_number: {$size: '$shelf_number'}, 
        users: {$size: '$users'}
    }}
])
```

But it returns a single object formatted like this:

```
{
 rxm_number: 2,
 shelf_number: 25,
 users: 34
}
```

How can I modify this query to achieve the result I wanted above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply using both values into the `_id` object inside `$group` like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "username": "$rxm_number",
        "shelf_number": "$shelf_number"
      },
      "users": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kOiiUBGvoHH)

Comment: Can not thank you enough! I used this and it works perfectly!